# node.js' debug module: how to avoid this tedious initialization?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, logging, error-logging

`node.js`' `debug` module is indeed neat. I am wondering if there is any way to prevent this tedious and overly redundant inizialization in each module:

```
require('debug').enable('module-name:log module-name:ERROR');
var log = require('debug')('module-name:log');
var error = require('debug')('module-name:ERROR');
```

As you can see it's redundant on two different levels: I need to "enable" the loggers before instantiating them, sending the same name twice as strings, and I need to write the module name. Is there any way to do this automagically?

Answer (score 2):

A few months ago I stumbled upon the same issue and as I couldn't find any solution I created [debug-logger](https://github.com/appscot/debug-logger). debug-logger is a wrapper around visionmedia/debug which will give you methods to log at different levels/namespaces. For example:

```
var log = require('debug-logger')('myapp');

log.trace("I'm a trace output");
log.debug("I'm a debug output");
log.log("I'm a log output");
log.info("I'm an info output");
log.warn("I'm a warn output");
log.error("I'm an error output");
```

Will print:

```
myapp:trace I'm a trace output +0ms
myapp:debug I'm a debug output +2ms
myapp:log   I'm a log output +0ms
myapp:info  I'm an info output +0ms
myapp:warn  I'm a warn output +1ms
myapp:error I'm an error output +0ms
```

In appropriate colors. It's very configurable as well.

That should fix your second issue. For the first issue, before you instantiate `debug`/`debug-logger` you can use the environment variable DEBUG such as, e.g.:

```
export DEBUG=*
```

That will enable all log levels/namespaces. Or, if you want to do it inside node:

```
process.env.DEBUG='*';
```

Let me know if that doesn't fully answer your question.